# Создание страниц и категорий (подкатегорий)

Tags: php

Здравствуйте! Необходимо сделать возможность создавать страницы из панели администратора, и чтобы у страниц были категории и потомки этих категории (только два уровня, категория-> подкатегория). Создаю страницы с помощью функции `fopen`(в самом проекте и добавляю в базу название страницы и ссылку на нее) и добавляю в базу категорию и id родительской категории(если есть). Как мне сделать так чтобы можно было перемещаться по страницам, чтобы в адресной строке отображалось `категория/подкатегория/страница1`. Сами ссылки(категории, подкатегории, страницы) необходимо получать из бд и чтобы на каждую страницу можно было попасть только по одной ссылке. Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: а причём тут фукция fopen () ? для каждой страницы вы создаёте отдельный файл ?  то что вы хотите, наверна логика URL Route, но трудно сказать что у вас там за движок и  т.д

Comment: @Arsen, ну это я так, чтобы было понятнее по я создаю именно файлы. А движок самописный

Comment: Если честно я такой логики не встречал в самописных движках, чтобы создавалось отдельная страница.... при написании движка, не лучше ли смотреть в сторону MVC ? не думаю что тут кто то сможет вам помочь, но вы можете погуглить и почитать о URL route MVC, может это наталкнёт вас на мысль... или посмотрите ЧПУ для сайтов